# provisioning a hostpool join domain failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm totally new to azure, my intention was to test a bit to validate if worth or not.

My goal would be to virtualize a desktop at the moment just for introduction reasons.

So, I started an azure free account, followed the first steps to start an azure AD Domain service, afterwards I tried to add a new ressource to create a vm with provisioning a hostpool.

It failed giving me an array joindomain provisioning failed.

I did it just via the portal following the azure documentation til create a tenant, I of course used also the PS commands, afterwards I followed the introduction to create a hostpool.
I used a new ressource group and the existing vnet.

Here also the script the portal gave me for downloading:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "virtualMachines_acme_0_name": {
        "defaultValue": "acme-0",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "availabilitySets_ACME_AVAILABILITYSET_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/c7c46e95-26bf-4666-a146-9427080e4ee2/resourceGroups/ACME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/ACME-AVAILABILITYSET",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "disks_acme_0_OsDisk_1_86a929acf8b14d85b34543064a89be09_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/c7c46e95-26bf-4666-a146-9427080e4ee2/resourceGroups/ACME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/acme-0_OsDisk_1_86a929acf8b14d85b34543064a89be09",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_acme_0_nic_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/c7c46e95-26bf-4666-a146-9427080e4ee2/resourceGroups/ACME/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/acme-0-nic",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_acme_0_name')]",
        "location": "southcentralus",
        "properties": {
            "availabilitySet": {
                "id": "[parameters('availabilitySets_ACME_AVAILABILITYSET_externalid')]"
            },
            "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "Standard_B1ms"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "imageReference": {
                    "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
                    "offer": "office-365",
                    "sku": "19h2-evd-o365pp",
                    "version": "latest"
                },
                "osDisk": {
                    "osType": "Windows",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_acme_0_name'), '_OsDisk_1_86a929acf8b14d85b34543064a89be09')]",
                    "createOption": "FromImage",
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
                        "id": "[parameters('disks_acme_0_OsDisk_1_86a929acf8b14d85b34543064a89be09_externalid')]"
                    },
                    "diskSizeGB": 127
                },
                "dataDisks": []
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_acme_0_name')]",
                "adminUsername": "chris",
                "windowsConfiguration": {
                    "provisionVMAgent": true,
                    "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
                },
                "secrets": [],
                "allowExtensionOperations": true,
                "requireGuestProvisionSignal": true
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "id": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_acme_0_nic_externalid')]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "diagnosticsProfile": {
                "bootDiagnostics": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            },
            "licenseType": "Windows_Client"
        }
    }
]
```

}

And this is the error in extensions/joindomain

```
[
{
    "code": "ComponentStatus/JoinDomainException for Option 3 meaning 'User Specified'/failed/1",
    "level": "Error",
    "displayStatus": "Provisioning failed",
    "message": "ERROR - Failed to join domain='cheyenneitoutlook.onmicrosoft.com', ou='', user='chris@cheyenneitoutlook.onmicrosoft.com', option='NetSetupJoinDomain, NetSetupAcctCreate' (#3 meaning 'User Specified'). Error code 1355"
},
{
    "code": "ComponentStatus/JoinDomainException for Option 1 meaning 'User Specified without NetSetupAcctCreate'/failed/1",
    "level": "Error",
    "displayStatus": "Provisioning failed",
    "message": "ERROR - Failed to join domain='cheyenneitoutlook.onmicrosoft.com', ou='', user='chris@cheyenneitoutlook.onmicrosoft.com', option='NetSetupJoinDomain' (#1 meaning 'User Specified without NetSetupAcctCreate'). Error code 1355"
}
```

]

Any help with explaation what I did wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your VMS cannot find or connect to the Azure AD DS managed domain. Take a look to [Connectivity issues for domain-join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/troubleshoot-domain-join#connectivity-issues-for-domain-join) and [Connectivity issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm#connectivity-issues).